# Check if JSON contains something C#

Tags: c#, .net, object, contains

Basically I get the current item stock from Supreme in JSON. Then I deserialize it to object. I have been trying to check if the object contains the desired item, and get its id.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if we had a complete code snippet with sample data that demonstrates the problem.  Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: it is hard to tell but it looks like this is an array and not a dictionary.  If it is an array you would need to itterate the array.

Comment: @BJMyers , posted the full code. I get error keyword when running :D

Comment: @AhmedSoliman This code is failing to convert the `shop_object` to a `IDictionary<string, object>`. Try `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)` instead of `error keyword` to help narrow down your issue.

Comment: @dvo i get "Specified cast is not valid."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data coming back from that endpoint, you probably need to look a little deeper, which is easiest to do with JObject's SelectToken method.

```
    var shop_object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(shop_json);
    Console.WriteLine(shop_object);

    try
    {
        if (shop_object.SelectTokens("$..name").Any(t => t.Value<string>() == DesiredItem))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n \n The desired item is in stock");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error keyword");
    }
```

Note that this uses an equality check on the string, so little details like the space at the end of `"Reversible Bandana Fleece Jacket "` can potentially throw you off.

Comment: Changed the equals to .Contains. Works well